# Proper way using array in this kind of situation or any expert advice?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The situation is I have a database that have a three tables, I wanted to insert data to each table using a single form.

In the database, I have three tables (table_a(profile), table_b(attributes(age,height) and table_c(favorite books(genre, title)

```
table_a

p_id(auto_increment)
p_name
p_surname


table_b

a_id(auto_increment)
p_id
a_age
a_height

table_c

b_id(auto_increment)
p_id
b_type
b_name
```

In class.php, I have three query that insert data to the three different table at the same time.

```
class nameOfClass{

function insertData(){
```

In query_1 the p_namea and p_surname is inserted to table_a

```
$query_1 = “ INSERT INTO table_a SET p_name=:p_name, p_surname=:p_surname”;

$stmt_1 = $this->conn->prepare(query_1);

$this->p_name=$this->p_name;
$this->p_surname=$this->p_surname;

$stmt_1->bindParam(':p_name', $this->p_name);
$stmt_1->bindParam(':p_surname', $this->p_surname);

if($stmt_1->execute()){
```

In query_2, p_id values was from the last inserted id on table_a and inserted to table_b along with a_age and a_height.

In the next query similar to table_b, p_id will come from the last inserted id from table_a and inserted to table_c along with b_type and b_name columns. b_type and b_values are array. because a p_name can have multiple book list.

```
    $query_2 = "INSERT INTO table_b SET p_id=:p_id, a_age=:a_age, a_height=:a_height;

            INSERT INTO table_c p_id=:p_id, b_type=:b_type, b_name=:b_name”;

    $stmt_2 = $this->conn->prepare($query_2);

        $this->p_id=$this->conn->lastInsertId();
        $this->a_age=$this->a_age;
        $this->a_height=$this->a_height;

        foreach($this->b_type AS $key => $value{
        $this->b_type=$value;
        $this->b_name=$this->b_name[$key];  
        }       

        $stmt_2->bindParam(':p_id', $this->p_id);
        $stmt_2->bindParam(':a_age', $this->a_age);
        $stmt_2->bindParam(':a_height', $this->a_height);



        $stmt_2->bindParam(':b_type', $this->b_type;
        $stmt_2->bindParam(':b_name', $this->b_name);


            if($stmt_2->execute()){
                         return  true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                     }
    }

}
```

on the form.php, in this form it connects to db, retrieve the class, and execute the function if form was submitted

```
<?php

include_once 'config/database.php';
include_once 'objects/class.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$nameofclass = new nameOfClass($db);

if($_POST){
    $nameofclass ->p_name=$_POST['p_name'];
    $nameofclass ->p_surname=$_POST['p_surname'];
    $nameofclass ->a_age=$_POST['a_age'];
    $nameofclass ->a_height=$_POST['p_height'];
    $nameofclass ->b_type=$_POST['b_type'];
    $nameofclass ->b_name=$_POST['b_name'];

 if($nameofclass->insertData()){

echo “success” ;
} else {

echo “error”;
 }
}

<form method="post">
```

table_a (regular input  box)

```
     <input type="text" name="p_name">
     <input type="text" name="p_surname">
```

table_b (regular input box)

```
      <input type="text" name="a_age">
      <input type="text" name="a_height">
```

table_c (dynamic add/remove input box using jquery( because a person can have multiple 
     books))

```
      <input type="text" name="b_type[]">
      <input type="text" name="b_name[]">
```

I can make it work, the two query regarding inserting data to table_a and table_b, but when I add the query about table_c that is where I get a problem I cannot make it work, it is using an array, I am not familiar with array, I am just copying codes around the web and slowly stitching them to get the result that I want.

I am not sure my code is correct. When I save it or click the submit button on query_1 is getting through which is inserting data to table_a.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Can you give us an example of your table_c query and tell us how exactly it doesn't work? Also, if you're not familiar with something, [nothing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) beats [learning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Actually that is all there is, my code, I just know that it would not save the record. And there is not much error code to begin with, no syntax error or whatsoever. I am hoping for suggesting, I just know that there is something wrong with my code.

Comment: Ok it is now working, except the insert in table_c, in b_name column, 
        $this->b_name=$this->b_name[$key];  
        this is not working, it cannot send a value or insert to the database.

Comment: Read those links I posted, if you receive an array, you have to iterate over it and store each entry separately.

Comment: and additional, there I input two values in the input box, but only one value was inserted  which is the second one, for example, I type in the input box, scifi(b_type), star trek(b_name, then I add another input box using jquery and i type horror(b_type), carrie(b_name). Only horror was send or inserted to the table in database